# Python format() pass one object

Tags: python, python-2.7, format

If i define the below custom class in Python:

```
class Test:
    hey = 'ho'
    yo = 'go'
    fo = 'sho'
```

Is there any way when using the string `format()` method to only have to pass in my object once and to then access that in all the arguments. Ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
test_class = Test()
print "Hey {0.hey}, let's {1.yo}. Fo' {2.sho}".format(test_class)
```

But I have to do this:

```
test_class = Test()
print "Hey {0.hey}, let's {1.yo}. Fo' {2.sho}".format(test_class, test_class, test_class)
```

Comment: Just reuse 0 that should do it

Comment: [fast forward to 3.6](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/)

Comment: @RyanHaining - they look cool. Shame I'm stuck on 2.7 :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as I posted this I realised I could just keyword arguments.

```
test_class = Test()
print "Hey {my_class.hey}, let's {my_class.yo}. Fo' {my_class.sho}".format(my_class=test_class)
```

In addition, as per my original question this is possible by just reusing the `0` positional argument as below:

```
test_class = Test()
print "Hey {0.hey}, let's {0.yo}. Fo' {0.sho}".format(test_class)
```

Also, as pointed out by Ryan in the comments Python 3.6+ comes with the new f-string, which means I could also do this:

```
test_class = Test()
print(f"Hey {test_class.hey}, let's {test_class.yo}. Fo' {test_class.sho}")
```

Answer (score 6):

As you found out for yourself, you can use keyword arguments, but you don't even have to do that:

```
In [4]: print("Hey {0.hey}, let's {0.yo}. Fo' {0.fo}".format(t))
Hey ho, let's go. Fo' sho

In [5]: class Test:
   ...:     hey = 'ho'
   ...:     yo = 'go'
   ...:     fo = 'sho'
   ...:

In [6]: t = Test()

In [7]: print("Hey {0.hey}, let's {0.yo}. Fo' {0.fo}".format(t))
Hey ho, let's go. Fo' sho
```

The `0` refers to the *zeroth* argument to `format`, the problem was you had no 1st and second argument, because you *didn't need it*.

### Warning as an aside:

Also, since you seem to be coming to python from other languages, you might be making a common mistake. Note that the way you have defined your class;

```
class Test:
    hey = 'ho'
    yo = 'go'
    fo = 'sho'
```

uses only *class-level* variables, which will act like *static members* to borrow terminology from other languages. In other words, `hey`, `yo`, and `fo` are not *instance attributes*, although your instances have access to the class-level namespace. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067/5014455). Of course, this doesn't matter for the purposes of this question, but it can lead to bugs if you don't understand the semantics of the class definition.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer @juanpa.arrivillaga. I have been caught out by class level variables before but this was more a question of formatting than the class semantics themselves, but thanks for the insight - always nice to get a reminder!

Answer (score 2):

{0.hey} is referring to the 'hey' attribute of the first argument passed to format.

So you just have to refer to the correct argument:

```
test_class = Test()
print "Hey {0.hey}, let's {0.yo}. Fo' {0.fo}".format(test_class)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for posterity, as said in the comments, anyone using Python 3.6 and greater can make use of the new *format string* literals specified in [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
class Test:
    hey = 'ho'
    yo = 'go'
    fo = 'sho'

test = Test()
print(f"Hey {test.hey}, let's {test.yo}. Fo' {test.fo}")
# Hey ho, let's go. Fo' sho
```

More format strings(f-strings for short) can be found in the [*Formatted string literals*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) section of Python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `1` and `2` by `0` you reuse the same argument and `format` does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can also use a dict to pass values:

```
dict_ = {
    "hey": 'ho',
    "yo":'go',
    "fo":'sho'
    }

print("Hey {0[hey]}, let's {0[yo]}. Fo' {0[fo]}".format(dict_))
```

Or an ordered dict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict_ = OrderedDict([('hey','ho'),('yo','go'),('fo','sho')])

print("Hey {}, let's {}. Fo' {}".format(*dict_.values()))
print("Hey {0}, let's {1}. Fo' {2}".format(*dict_.values()))
```